# looping through object variables

Tags: python, for-loop

In the following `for` loop I would like to have `mesh` be `mesh_6`, `mesh_31`, etc.
Finally store the names of each mesh object and plot them.

No need to get into the detail of the script, it works hard coded outside of a loop.

I've seen a few examples, but I'm not understanding it.

```
contexts = [6, 31, 35, 43, 10]
meshes = []

for context in contexts:
    c = str(context)
    r = random.uniform(0, 1)
    g = random.uniform(0, 1)
    b = random.uniform(0, 1)

    path = "E:/gygaia/database/contexts/99_526/" + c + ".ply"

    mesh = read_triangle_mesh(path)
    mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
    mesh.paint_uniform_color([r, g, b])
    mesh.purge()

    meshes.append(mesh)

draw_geometries([meshes])
```

EDIT

Here is the script not in a loop

```
mesh_6 = read_triangle_mesh("E:/gygaia/database/contexts/99_526/6.ply")
mesh_6.compute_vertex_normals()
mesh_6.paint_uniform_color([random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)])
mesh_6.purge()

mesh_31 = read_triangle_mesh("E:/gygaia/database/contexts/99_526/31.ply")
mesh_31.compute_vertex_normals()
mesh_31.paint_uniform_color([random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)])
mesh_31.purge()

mesh_35 = read_triangle_mesh("E:/gygaia/database/contexts/99_526/35.ply")
mesh_35.compute_vertex_normals()
mesh_35.paint_uniform_color([random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)])
mesh_35.purge()

draw_geometries([
    # big pit
    mesh_6,
    mesh_31,
    mesh_35,
    ])
```

So I am tring to simplify the code so I only need add the number of the file to the list.

Comment: dynamically setting variable names in python isn't very "pythonic", my suggestion would be to build a dictionary with keys as strings set to `mesh_6`, etc.

Comment: Why? What you have looks OK.

Comment: because `mesh` is the object that the ply is assigned to, this currently appends the mesh object to the meshes list. What I need for the `draw_geometries` to work is only the object name, so I need mesh_6, mesh_32 etc to be objects, `mesh_6 = read...` then `draw_geometries([mesh_6, mesh_32]).

Comment: What do you need the object names for ?
And what does the `draw_geometries` function expect as parameter ? I guess a list of objects, not a list of names.

Comment: @Bas I've edited the question to add a none looped version hopefully that explains better what I am trying to do?

Comment: Just use *a container* like a list or a dict. There is no need to dynamically create variables here, in general, there essentially never is.

Comment: would you be able to give an example, I've come from php so that might explain why my approach seems strange to established python users.

Comment: For the function `draw_geometries`, the variable names are not available ... So this seems useless.
If you come from php, you might read this nice explanation about passing variables to functions: [link](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`draw_geometries()` doesn't need object variable names, just a list containing the objects themselves, so I believe only the last line of your code needs to be changed:

From:

```
draw_geometries([meshes])
```

To:

```
draw_geometries(meshes)
```

because `meshes` already is a `list`.